# Class property setter is not throwing expected exception c#

Tags: c#, exception

I have a Class called "person" that takes name, age and weight properties. I am trying to make sure that when a person object is instantiated, the name property is at least 5 characters and contains a space. I want to throw a new exception if not.
Here is the setter for name prop:

```
 public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.name;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value.Length < 5 || value.Contains(" ") == false)
                    {
                        
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid");
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.name = value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've created a couple person objects with invalid data and no exception is thrown. My plan is to use a try catch block in the constructor to handle the exception. Am I going about this the wrong way?

There is no user input in this program, it is just an assignment. We are supposed to instantiate some person objects with invalid data to test our exception handling code. Here is an example of an object that should throw an exception:

```
person p1 = new person("hi", 26, 165);
```

here is the class constructor:

```
 public person(string Name, string Age, double Weight)
            {
               
               this.name = Name;               
                
               this.weight = Weight;
                
                              
                try
                {
                    this.age = int.Parse(Age); 
                   
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    WriteLine("Age must be an integer number. Age set to 0 by default.");
                    this.age = 0;
                }              
                
            }
```

This is building on a previous assignment where we had to take age as a string value and try to parse it.

Comment: Can you add expression you wrote to get an exception?

Comment: Don't use exceptions to depict code flow, it's a bad design. It would also help to show how the `Name` property is set...

Comment: You can't imagine to ever have a `Person` with less than 5 characters? I would not do it. Instead validate the input `Name` where you get it but avoid having it in the constructor or the property of the `Person` class. On that way it is more reusable.

Comment: Do not throw from a property setter.

Comment: this is an assignment so I'm just following the required validation. Also there is no input from user. I am just instantiating a person Object like this:  person P1 = new person("hi", 26, 165). Where would the correct place to throw the exception be? this is building on a previous assignment where we used a try catch in the constructor.

Comment: Bono would not like your application...

Comment: Kindly include your intanciated person object? How did you set the Name value on each object?

Comment: can you add the constructor code too

Comment: I suspect you are setting `this.name` in the constructor and not using the `Name` property setter.

Comment: Side node: shorter `set` implementation `set => name = value >= 5 && value.Contains(' ') ? value : throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));`

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `Name` setter in the constructor, so the property setter is not being called. Use

```
this.Name = Name;
```

in the constructor to call the property setter.

Also, a few nitpicks, but I would also use :

```
if (value.Length < 5 || !value.Contains(" "))
```

instead of  `== false`, and give a better error message:

```
throw new ArgumentException("Name must be at least 5 characters and must contain a space", "Name");
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

your constructor should be like thus

```
public person(string name, string age, double weight)
        {
           
           this.Name= name;               
            
           this.Age= age;
           this.Weight = weight;                
        }
```

Then the setters will invoke and exception will be thrown if needed

Answer (score 0):

You Name property is not thrown an exception , since you don't call setter.
Use this

```
Name=name;
```

and it is a common practice to use _ for private members, so use _name instead of name in your Name getter/setter.

IMHO it is a bad idea use exceptions to depict code flow. So  you don't need _name, defined Name as

```
public string Name {get; set; }
```

and move a validation to a constructor,

```
public person(string name, string age, double weight)
 {
      Weigt=weght;

    if (name.Length < 5 || !value.Contains(" ") )
Consodle. WriteLine ($"Name {name} is not valid. Must be at least 5 characters and contain a space");              
   else  Name = name
       
 if (Double.TryParse(age, out number)) Age=age;
  else 
 Console.WriteLine($"Unable to parse age {age}.");    
       
}
```